# Ionic: hide ion-footer from specific page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to `ionic1 framework` and working on *`sidemenu ionic app`*.  I have the footer bar added in the index.html file.

How to hide footer from specific page?

Comment: try to use hide on your specific page using ng-hide

Comment: Thank you @sa E Chowdary for the reply.   I have already tried this but its not working properly , ng-hide hides from all the pages

Comment: for that you need to maintain a root scope value which allows you to show in all pages but you need to make it as false or something which hides in your particular view

Comment: ok i will try it thank you so much :)